# PHP mysqli_query() No funciona

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy aprendiendo a conectar `MySQLi PHP` con MySQL, hice este CRUD pero no funciona correctamente. Solamente funciona en la tabla `Alumno`, pero no en la tabla `Matricula`.

Ya intente con `mysqli_multi_query()` y con distintas formas de hacerlo funcionar y no encuentro como.

```
include 'Conexion.php';
if(isset($_POST['Registrar']))
{ 
$IDalumn = "";
$nomalumn ="";
$apealumn ="";
$IDalumn = $_POST['IdAlu'];
$nomalumn = $_POST['NomA'];
$apealumn = $_POST['ApeA'];
$IDgrado = $_POST["IDgrado"];
$fechaingre = $_POST["FechaIngre"];


$query1 = "INSERT INTO matricula(IDalumno,IDgrado,FechaIngreso)VALUES 
('$IDalumn','$IDgrado','$fechaingre')";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO alumno(IDalumno,Nombres,Apellidos)VALUES 
('$IDalumn','$nomalumn','$apealumn')";
$Create = mysqli_query($conexion,$query1);
$Create1 = mysqli_query($conexion,$query2);

mysqli_close($conexion);

}
```

Aquì esta el código HTML

```
<table>  
    <ul> 
      <li>
          <input name="IdAlu" id="IdAlu" type="text" maxlength="5"> 
Digite la identificacion del alumno: 
      </li>
      <li>
          <input name="NomA" id="NomA" type="text" maxlength="40"> 
Digite Los nombres del alumno:
      </li>
      <li>
          <input name="ApeA" id="ApeA" type="text" maxlength="40"> 
Digite Los apellidos del alumno:
      </li>
      <li>
          <input name="IDgrado" id="IDgrado" type="text" 
maxlength="2" > Digite la identificacion de grado al que ingresa el 
alumno:
      </li>
      <li>
          <input name="FechaIngre" id="FechaIngre" type="date"> 
Digite la fecha en la que ingresa el alumno:
      </li>
        <input type="submit" name="Registrar" value="AGREGAR"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Actualizar" Value="ACTUALIZAR">


    </ul>    
  </table>
```

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis aquí: `)VALUES`, debe ir un espacio entre el paréntesis y `VALUES`. No obstante, tu código es mejorable. Te propondré una solución completa, basada en un código controlado y seguro.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi propuesta. La cual incluye lo siguiente:

1. Uso de consultas preparadas para dar seguridad al código. No usar este tipo de consultas en datos que provienen desde fuentes externas a la misma consulta puede poner en serio riesgo no solo la base de datos, sino todo el sistema.
2. Uso de programación orientada a objetos en vez de programación procedural. Es más clara y más adaptada a los tiempos modernos. Si quieres usar la programación procedural el código de puede adaptar.
3. Se escribe un código controlado, usando una variable que va recogiendo en el código todas sus eventualidades. Al final se imprimirá el mensaje contenido en ese variable. Para mi, esa es una forma de no escribir código *mudo*. Aquí, el código está obligado a decir lo que le está ocurriendo en todo momento. De ese modo, el programador controla al código, y no al revés.

Si tienes alguna duda, puedes preguntar en comentarios.

Aquí va el código, espero te sirva:

```
<?php

include 'Conexion.php';
if(isset($_POST['Registrar']))
{
    if ($conexion){
        $IDalumn = $_POST['IdAlu'];
        $nomalumn = $_POST['NomA'];
        $apealumn = $_POST['ApeA'];
        $IDgrado = $_POST['IDgrado'];
        $fechaingre = $_POST['FechaIngre'];
        $arrResultado=array();

        $matriculaSQL = 'INSERT INTO matricula (IDalumno, IDgrado, FechaIngreso) VALUES (?,?,?)';
        $stmt=$conexion->prepare($matriculaSQL);
        if ($stmt){
            $stmt->bind_param('sss', $IDalumn, $IDgrado, $fechaingre);
            $crearMatricula=$stmt->execute();

            if($crearMatricula){
                $arrResultado['mensaje']='¡Matrícula creada! Se agregaron '.$stmt->affected_rows.' a la tabla.';
            }else{
                $arrResultado['mensaje']='Error creando la Matricula: '.$stmt->error;
            }
            $stmt->close();

        }else{
            $arrResultado['mensaje']='Error en la consulta SQL de Matricula: '.$conexion->error;
        }


        $alumnoSQL = 'INSERT INTO alumno (IDalumno, Nombres, Apellidos) VALUES (?,?,?)';
        $stmt=$conexion->prepare($alumnoSQL);
        if ($stmt){
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $IDalumn, $nomalumn, $apealumn);
            $crearAlumno=$stmt->execute();

            if($crearAlumno){
                $arrResultado['mensaje'] .= '<br />¡Alumno creado! Se agregaron '.$stmt->affected_rows.' a la tabla.';
            }else{
                $arrResultado['mensaje']='<br />Error creando el Alumno: '.$stmt->error;
            }
            $stmt->close();


        }else{
            $arrResultado['mensaje']='<br />Error en la consulta SQL de Alumno: '.$conexion->error;
        }

    }else{
        $arrResultado['mensaje']='Error en la conexión a la base de datos';
    }

}else{
    $arrResultado['mensaje']='No hay datos en Registrar';
}

echo $arrResultado['mensaje'];

?>
```

Comment: +1, Muchas gracias amigo!, eres el mejor :)